# Getting enum name based on value java in run time

Tags: java

I need to get the enum name based on value. I am given with enum class and value and need to pick the corresponding name during run time .

I have a class called Information as below.

```
class Information {
    private String value;
    private String type;
    private String cValue;
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public String getcValue() {
        return cValue;
    }
    public void setcValue(String cValue) {
        this.cValue = cValue;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Information inf = new Information();
        inf.setType("com.abc.SignalsEnum");
        inf.setValue("1");
    }
}

class SignalEnum {
    RED("1"), GREEN("2"), ORANGE("3");
    private String sign;
    SignalEnum(String pattern) {
        this.sign = pattern;
    }
}
class MobileEnum {
    SAMSUNG("1"), NOKIA("2"), APPLE("3");
    private String mobile;
    MobileEnum(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

In run time i will come to know the enum name using the attribute type from the Information class and also i am getting the value. I need to figure out the corresponding enum to set the value for cValue attribute of Information class.

Just for example i have provided two enums like SignalEnum and MobileEnum but in my actual case i will get one among 100 enum types. Hence i dont want to check type cast. I am looking for some solution using reflection to se the cValue.

Comment: i dont know what type of enum i will get in run time . Hence it would be dificult to maintain hashmap. I just need to check whether its type of enum if yes then i need to somehow get the enum name by passing value. The existing map solution will work for fixed number of enums, In my case i dont know what type of enum i will get.

Comment: So you will get for instance `"1"` and from that you want to extract what exactly? Also is there a reason why you are not using the built-in Enum type (or is it a typo in the question)?

Comment: Dynamically figure out which type of enum it is

Comment: But both of your examples has an item with the value `"1"`?

Comment: That is fine . Based on instance type we can get the appropriate enum. For example if the instance is of type SignalEnum we will get RED for value "1" and SAMSUNG in case if the instance is of type Mobile

Comment: The challenge here is we have hundreds of enums so it would be quite difficult .Can you throw some light on how to check the instance type without comparing all the hundreds of enums with the current object( object instanceOf  enum1 or object instanceOf enum2 ....... object instance of enum100 etc... which is quite difficult i feel.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple resolver for any enum class. 
Since reflection operations are expensive, it's better to prepare all required data once and then just query for it.

```
class EnumResolver {

    private Map<String, Enum> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public EnumResolver(String className) {
        try {
            Class enumClass = Class.forName(className);

            // look for backing property field, e.g. "sign" in SignalEnum
            Field accessor = Arrays.stream(enumClass.getDeclaredFields())
                    .filter(f -> f.getType().equals(String.class))
                    .findFirst()
                    .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchFieldException("Not found field to access enum backing value"));

            accessor.setAccessible(true);

            // populate map with pairs like ["1" => SignalEnum.RED, "2" => SignalEnum.GREEN, etc]
            for (Enum e : getEnumValues(enumClass)) {
                map.put((String) accessor.get(e), e);
            }

            accessor.setAccessible(false);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public Enum resolve(String backingValue) {
        return map.get(backingValue);
    }

    private <E extends Enum> E[] getEnumValues(Class<E> enumClass) throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        Field f = enumClass.getDeclaredField("$VALUES");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object o = f.get(null);
        f.setAccessible(false);
        return (E[]) o;
    }
}
```

And here is simple JUnit test

```
public class EnumResolverTest {

    @Test
    public void testSignalEnum() {
        EnumResolver signalResolver = new EnumResolver("com.abc.SignalEnum");
        assertEquals(SignalEnum.RED, signalResolver.resolve("1"));
        assertEquals(SignalEnum.GREEN, signalResolver.resolve("2"));
        assertEquals(SignalEnum.ORANGE, signalResolver.resolve("3"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testMobileEnum() {
        EnumResolver mobileResolver = new EnumResolver("com.abc.MobileEnum");
        assertEquals(MobileEnum.SAMSUNG, mobileResolver.resolve("1"));
        assertEquals(MobileEnum.NOKIA, mobileResolver.resolve("2"));
        assertEquals(MobileEnum.APPLE, mobileResolver.resolve("3"));
    }
}
```

And again for performance sake you can also instantiate these various resolvers once and put them into a separate Map

```
Map<String, EnumResolver> resolverMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
resolverMap.put("com.abc.MobileEnum", new EnumResolver("com.abc.MobileEnum"));
resolverMap.put("com.abc.SignalEnum", new EnumResolver("com.abc.SignalEnum"));
// etc

Information inf = new Information();
inf.setType("com.abc.SignalsEnum");
inf.setValue("1");

SignalEnum red = (SignalEnum) resolverMap.get(inf.getType()).resolve(inf.getValue());
```

Comment: Can you throw some light on the statement on  f.getType().equals(String.class). why are we flitering on String class

Comment: @mohan because backing properties in your enum classes have String type - `private String sign;` & `private String mobile;`. As long as they named differently you shouldn't rely on their name but on rely on type instead. Of course you can rename all that properties to the common name e.g. `value` and then search by name - `.filter(f -> f.getName().equals("value"))`